# move to an element in scrollable content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a standard scrollable content with some block elements.

I want to find out position of the div (relative to content top) and move scroll to that possiton. Is it possible? Maybe with jquery.

Comment: Maybe http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-scroll-elements-smoothly-in-javascript-jquery-without-plugins/.

Comment: Do you need to animate that scrolling, or just scroll to an arbitrary point (to whatever given element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in jQuery it is possible.

You can get the position of any id like this: `$(divId).position().top`
and use `scrollTop` to set where the scrollbar goes.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K67Gk/2/), does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery to do something like that:

```
function scroll(element, parent){
    $(parent).animate({ scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - $(parent).offset().top }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'swing'});
}
```

Check the [demo](http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/scroll/ScrollDemo.html).

Comment: Thanks it was helpful, the problem is that you need to wrap the elements in scrollable content and use elements offset minus wrapper (not scrollable parent) offset.